# ¿Como hacer la sobrecarga del operador subíndice para un array de dos dimensiones en C++?

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo una clase que tiene como atributo un vector de vectores de enteros (int) que representa un array de dos dimensiones.

```
class Matrix{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mtx_;
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns){
        mtx_.resize(rows);

        for(auto &row : mtx_){
            row.resize(columns);
        }
    }
    std::size_t row() const{
        return mtx_.size();
    }
    std::size_t column() const{
        return mtx_.front().size();
    }
};
```

Pero al hacer la sobrecarga del operador subíndice.

```
std::vector<int> &operator[](std::size_t index){
    return mtx_[index];
}
```

Me doy cuenta de que acabo exponiendo detalles de implementación interna de mi clase, lo que daría lugar a modificar cosas que no se deberían poder hacer desde fuera, por ejemplo redimensionar una fila cualquiera.

```
int main(){
    Matrix matrix(3,3);

    matrix[0].resize(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Entonces la matrix deja de ser de 3x3 porque la primera fila ahora es una fila de 5 columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sobrecarga del [operador[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) se puede modificar para que acepte varios parámetros a partir de C++23. En tu código podrías implementarlo así:

```
int& operator[](int x, int y){
     return mtx_[x][y];
}
```

Y utilizarlo así:

```
matrix[x, y]
```

---

Por cierto, ten en cuenta que el procesador tarda menos cuando la información está en un mismo lugar porque seguramente esté en caché. Sin embargo, la información de cada vector está en un lugar diferente.

Mejor considera lo siguiente:

```
std::vector<int> mtx_;
int columns;

Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns) : mtx_(rows * columns), columns(columns)
{
}

int& operator[](int row, int column){
     return mtx_[column + row * columns];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones:

1. **Devolver un objeto proxy que represente la fila o la columna**: El objeto proxi encapsulará los detalles evitando que se puedan acceder a ellos *maliciosamente*.

   ```
   class Matrix {
       std::vector<std::vector<int>> mtx_;

    struct Fila
       {
           friend class Matrix;

        int &operator[](int i) { return fila[i]; }
        int &operator[](int i) const { return fila[i]; }

    private:
        Fila(Matrix &m, int fila) :
            fila{m.mtx_[fila]}
        {
        }
        std::vector<int> &fila;
    };

   public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns)
    {
        mtx_.resize(rows);

        for(auto &row : mtx_) {
            row.resize(columns);
        }
    }

    std::size_t row() const {
        return mtx_.size();
    }

    std::size_t column() const {
        return mtx_.front().size();
    }

    Fila fila(int i)
    {
        return {*this, i};
    }
   };

   int main()
   {
    Matrix m(3, 3);

    m.fila(1)[1] = 1;

    std::cout << m.fila(0)[0] << m.fila(1)[1];

    return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Crear una funcción de acceso doblemente indizada**: En lugar del operador de indizado, una función que acepte dos índices:

   ```
   int &elemento(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)                         { return mtx_[x][y]; }
   const int &elemento(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const             { return mtx_[x][y]; }
   int &elemento(std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> &id)              { return mtx_[id.first][id.second]; }
   const int &elemento(std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> &id)  const { return mtx_[id.first][id.second]; }
   ```
3. **Usar el operador de indizado de C++23**: En el estándar de C++23 se aprobó un cambio para que el operador de indizado pudiese recibir más de un parámetro:

   ```
   int &operator[](std::size_t x, std::size_t y)             { return mtx_[index]; }
   const int &operator[](std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const { return mtx_[index]; }
   ```